# Finding Nash Equilibrium using Linear Program with strategy constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Finding the Nash Equilibrium **p** in mixed strategies of a 2-player, symmetric zero-sum game with 3 pure strategies can be done by solving LP:

max $(0, 0, 0, 1)^{T}(p_1, \ p_2,\  p_3,\ \epsilon)$

s.t. $A \geq b$

Where A is:

\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & -1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & -1 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

and $b = (0,0,0)$

i.e. We maximize our worse payoff.

Now suppose player 2, who plays $q = (q_1,\ q_2,\ q_3)$ is under the constraint $q_1 + q_2 = c$, for some $c$ $0 \leq c \leq 1$.

Can this be solved?  Thanks.

Comment: you should provide some background info about how the linear optimization problem solves "We maximize our worse payoff." or how $q$ can appear

Comment: @LinAlg `q` is the opponent's strategy.  It is not needed in the original "unconstrained" problem.  For more information on the formulation, page 38 of this document might help: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/mat.pdf

Comment: Hi! Did you eventually figure out what are conditions for such a constrained optimal mixed strategy to exist?

Comment: @BenUsman Hi, unfortunately I made no progress on this.  There are however, iterative algorithms which can converge to NE.